# Early stopping val_loss not resetting in k fold cross validation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

During my k fold cross validation session with a regression analysis using deep learning, my early stopping does not reset itself during the for loop.

The code that I use, where you can ignore some of the functions that are not visible right now because they are not relevant, they just preprocess the data a bit (think of the functions normalize() etc:

```
model_checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('models/graph_model.h5', monitor='val_loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
es = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, verbose=1, min_delta=0.001, monitor='val_loss', mode='min',baseline=None)#, restore_best_weights=True)

#%%
def main():

    inputs = np.load('data/inputs.npy', allow_pickle = True)
    targets = np.load('data/targets.npy', allow_pickle = True)
    meta = np.load('data/meta.npy', allow_pickle = True)

    graph_input = np.load('data/normalized_laplacian.npy', allow_pickle=True)
    graph_input = np.array([graph_input] * inputs.shape[0])

    graph_features = np.load('data/station_coords.npy', allow_pickle=True)
    graph_features = np.array([graph_features] * inputs.shape[0])


    inputsK, targetsK, metaK = k_fold_split(inputs, targets, meta)
    
    mse_scores_pgv = []
    mse_scores_pga = []


    for k in range(0,5):
        keras.backend.clear_session()
        tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

        trainInputsAll, trainTargets, trainMeta, testInputsAll, testTargets, testMeta = merge_splits(inputsK, targetsK, metaK, k)
    
        # if network_choice == 'network_1':
        train_graphinput = graph_input[0:length_size_max,:,:]
        train_graphfeatureinput = graph_features[0:length_size_max,:,:]

        test_graphinput = graph_input[0:length_size_min,:,:]
        test_graphfeatureinput = graph_features[0:length_size_min,:,:]

     
        trainInputs, trainMaxes = normalize(trainInputsAll[:, :, :, :])
        testInputs, testMaxes = normalize(testInputsAll[:, :, :, :])


        model = build_model(testInputs[0].shape)
        


        print(model.summary())
        history = model.fit(x=[trainInputs, trainMaxes, train_graphinput,train_graphfeatureinput], 
                            y=targets_to_list(trainTargets),
              epochs=100, batch_size=30,
              validation_data=([testInputs, testMaxes,test_graphinput,test_graphfeatureinput], targets_to_list(testTargets)),verbose=0,callbacks=[model_checkpoint,es])#
       
        
        model.load_weights('models/graph_model.h5')

        print('val_loss: ',history.history['val_loss'][-1])

        predictions = model.predict([testInputs, testMaxes, test_graphinput, test_graphfeatureinput])

        mse_scores_pgv.append(np.round(np.square(np.subtract(predictions[1], testTargets[:,:,1])).mean(), 4))
        mse_scores_pga.append(np.round(np.square(np.subtract(np.array(predictions)[0,:,:], testTargets[:,:,0])).mean(), 4))
        print() 
        print('MSE of this fold = ',np.square(np.subtract(predictions[1], testTargets[:,:,1])).mean()) 



        keras.backend.clear_session()
        tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
```

This results in the following output in my terminal:

```
...
...

Epoch 00077: val_loss did not improve from 0.87589

Epoch 00078: val_loss did not improve from 0.87589
Epoch 00078: early stopping


val_loss:  0.8850340843200684
MSE of this fold =  0.147142121367


____________________________________________________________________________________________

Epoch 00001: val_loss did not improve from 0.87589

Epoch 00002: val_loss did not improve from 0.87589
```

Does anybody know where this mistake is coming from? I tried adding the clear session commands to the code at the beginning of the loop and after but that does not help.

Thanks in advance!

---------- edit 16:07 ------------
added output from model.get_weights()[0]

```
Epoch 00009: val_loss did not improve from 1.40527

Epoch 00010: val_loss did not improve from 1.40527
mean weights are -0.00040930937393568456, min  = -0.049326639622449875 and max = 0.04853195697069168


MSE of this fold =  0.260457055618




Epoch 00001: val_loss did not improve from 1.40527

Epoch 00002: val_loss did not improve from 1.40527

Epoch 00003: val_loss did not improve from 1.40527

Epoch 00004: val_loss did not improve from 1.40527

Epoch 00005: val_loss did not improve from 1.40527

Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 1.40527

Epoch 00007: val_loss did not improve from 1.40527

Epoch 00008: val_loss did not improve from 1.40527

Epoch 00009: val_loss did not improve from 1.40527

Epoch 00010: val_loss did not improve from 1.40527
mean weights are -0.0005600177682936192, min  = -0.051178786903619766 and max = 0.05091467127203941

MSE of this fold =  0.28202234982
```

-------------- build model function without some contents ------------

```
def build_model(input_shape): # houden

    reg_const = 0.0001
    activation_func = 'relu'

    wav_input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape, name='wav_input')
    graph_input = layers.Input(shape=(39,39), name='graph_input')
    graph_features = layers.Input(shape=(39,2), name='graph_features')

    conv1 = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(1, 125), strides=(1, 2),  activation=activation_func, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg_const), name='conv1')(wav_input)

    conv1_new = ..... (conv1)


  -----------------------

    conv1_new = layers.Flatten()(conv1_new)
    conv1_new = layers.concatenate(inputs=[conv1_new, meta])
    conv1_new = layers.Dropout(0.4, seed=seed)(conv1_new)
    merged = layers.Dense(128)(conv1_new)


    pga = layers.Dense(39)(merged)
    pgv = layers.Dense(39)(merged)
    sa03 = layers.Dense(39)(merged)
    sa10 = layers.Dense(39)(merged)
    sa30 = layers.Dense(39)(merged)
    
    final_model = models.Model(inputs=[wav_input, meta_input, graph_input, graph_features], outputs=[pga, pgv, sa03, sa10, sa30]) #, pgv, sa03, sa10, sa30
    
    rmsprop = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.)
    # adamopt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
    # final_model.compile(optimizer=rmsprop, loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
    final_model.compile(optimizer=rmsprop, loss='mse')#, metrics=['mse'])
    
    return final_model
```

Comment: Early stopping grabs the input out of fit history, maybe there is a problem on your model that is not being reset every loop. Why don't you check `model.get_weights()` after bulding the model to see if these are changing every iteration.

Comment: okay will investigate right away

Comment: okay so i checked by looking at the model.get_weights()[0] and look at the numbers, which seem to be different each run. I have added this output to the question visible above for clarity

Comment: Are you printing your model weights after training or after compiling the model? Indeed numbers are different but yield the same result on loss. Can you please share the `build_model` function?

Comment: these model weights are printed after training. The problem with sharing the build_model() function is that I cannot share the content of the model architecture so those lines are not in there if that is no issue.

Comment: one thing i also notice is that in the other iterations of the for loop, the early stopping will go on further than the patience parameter. This seems to suggest that the operations all work fine but that the value that the early stopping is printing for the val_loss is not correct. When I look at the number of epochs that each for loop iteration performs I see numbers around 50-80 epochs.

Comment: I think I got the solution, the message "Epoch 000XX: val_loss did not improve from XX" is the output of the checkpointer, so unless the val_loss is improved, then the model won't be saved.

Comment: yes indeed but in each iteration the val_loss should be reset, which now does not happen. Or this is okay and we just say that the best run of all these 5 kfold iterations is the result of running this code, that would also be a solution. In that way, the best epoch of all the iterations (100 epochs * 5 epochs) is the result.

Comment: The value is not reset because the saved model `models/graph_model.h5` stores the best iteration. The best model will be saved, but you should consider saving each model in a separate file to compare them later.

Comment: But i reset it by newly defining my model right by running model = build_model(testInputs[0].shape)? That is the part that i do not understand fully yet. Maybe a workaround will be not using a modelcheckpoint and only say restore best weights with the early stopping since that does not work with any .h5 files at all.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you `fit` a new model, the `model_checkpoint` will compare the current model againts `models/graph_model.h5` a will try to save if the corresponding `val_loss` is improved.

Since this is cross validation I believe your function `merge_splits` return a different validation data for every iteration so having just one saved model is not right because you cannot compare model from iteration 1 with model form iteration 2.

The idea of cross validation is check whether the model is actually generalizing the data so your scores: `mse_scores_pgv` and `mse_scores_pgv` should not vary for each model.

You could save each iteration model, for example inside the for loop:

```
# ...
model = build_model(testInputs[0].shape)
iteration_checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    f'models/graph_model_iteration_{k}.h5',
    monitor='val_loss',
    verbose=1,
    save_best_only=True
)

# Fit the model
history = model.fit(
    x=[trainInputs, trainMaxes, train_graphinput, train_graphfeatureinput],
    y=targets_to_list(trainTargets),
    epochs=100, batch_size=30,
    validation_data=(
        [testInputs, testMaxes,test_graphinput,test_graphfeatureinput],
        targets_to_list(testTargets)
    ),
    verbose=0,
    callbacks=[iteration_checkpoint, es]
)

model.load_weights(f'models/graph_model_iteration_{k}.h5')
print('val_loss: ',history.history['val_loss'][-1])
```

Comment: ahhh okay that makes sense! And then in another script check the prediction scores for each model that is now saved as graph_model_iteration_1-2-3-etc? I have set a seed for the random split of the data so i will receive the same data each time

Comment: The predictions itself provide good information but again, the idea of cross validation is to check the performance of the model in unseed data. The results of each fold is stored  in `mse_scores_pgv` and `mse_scores_pga`, you might just need to review the content of these lists.